# ANT FilterChains and FilterReaders

Tags: ant

I have a file depends.txt containing 2015001, 2015002, 2015003. I created an ANT target that have the following code.  I tried searching on how to use the stringtokenizer attribute but the descriptions are vague.  I would like to run the target and get
2015001
2015002
2015003
All the help are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
 `<loadfile srcFile="depends.txt" property="depends"/>
     <filterchain>
         <tokenfilter>
              <stringtokenizer delims="," />
         </tokenfilter>
   </filterchain>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant's filterreaders can modify the input read by Ant and the `tokenfilter` is one of them.  The `tokenfilter` doesn't do anything by itself but rather coordinates two different actors - a `tokenizer` and a `filter`.

The `filter` is the thing that performs the real action and the `tokenizer` is responsible for feeding the `filter` with chunks of text it works on.  The separation of `tokenizer` and `filter`s allows the same algorithm - say `uniq` - to be applied to either words or lines depending on the `tokenizer`.

In your example you only specify a `tokenizer` but no `filter` so the output is the same as the input.  IIUC you only want to strip the comma characters, in that case

```
<loadfile srcFile="depends.txt" property="depends">
  <filterchain>
    <deletecharacters chars=","/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

should do the trick.